# Are Kanto Pokemon in GSC also version-exclusive?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

All I can find is information on Johto version exclusives. Are the Pokemon available in Kanto the same for Gold and Silver? Or are they different like in Generation 1? Do they have the same exclusives as a Generation 1 game?

Comment: Can you quote or show us the links to where you have been looking? One would think web sites like Bulbapedia or Serebii would be quite accurate with these details.

Answer (score 2):

[Here on Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Game-exclusive_Pok%C3%A9mon) you can find a complete List of all the version exclusive Pokemon for each game in each generation and even spin-off games.

Regardless of the region you are in, these rules will apply.